# Retrieving option id with bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I'm using bootstrap select, here is my code:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option id="mk12bd">Mustard</option>
    <option id="tk22fd">Ketchup</option>
    <option id="mg32br">Relish</option>
  </select>
```

Suppose I perform $(".selectpicker").val() then I would get back this: mk12bd or whatever was selected.

But when I perform:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

If I perform $(".selectpicker").val() then I would get back this: "Mustard" or whatever was selected.

My original layout is lost and my id's are gone with it, my ui logic uses them to call some web services, is there any way to keep them in the new layout using bootstrap-select?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just realize that I was wrong... I'm sorry, I had to change "id" for "value" in every <option></...>. I'm leaving this question and this comment as a reminder of how stupid I can be.

Comment: FWIW, I came here looking for the same thing, and this helped!

Comment: This helped me as well!